# RxJS Websocket Next as obsrvable that can be subscribed to

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- Create a websocket Service (DONE)
- Open a websocket to the server (DONE)
- Single out the Next property so that other components can directly subscribe to it, using best practices.

I understand the websocket itself is an observable, but I'm specifically looking to single out the Next property (which is similar to websocket onMessage received). I do not want components to receive Error messages.

What would be the best practice for doing the above? Below is my some of the code with notes.

Thank you!

Using Angular 14, RxJS 7

```
private ws$ = webSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:2015');

public connect(): void {
  this.ws$.subscribe(
    {
      next:   msg => 
      {
        //Make this property Observable and call it using the onMessage() method below the 
        console.log('message received: ' + JSON.stringify(msg))
      },
      error:  err => { console.log('error: ' + err) },   
      complete:() => { console.log('closed: ' + complete') }
    });
    
}

//Component would call this function and ONLY receive Next messages from this.ws$ (webSocket)
public onMessage(): Observable<any>
{
    return new Observable<any>;
}
```

The component

```
  private wsService;
  //private obsB:any;
  constructor(wsService: WebsocketService) 
  { 
    this.wsService = wsService;
    this.wsService.onMessage().subscribe()
      {
        next:   (msg:any) => 
        {
          console.log('message received: ' + JSON.stringify(msg))
          this.doStuffInTheComponent(msg); //Method in Component
        }
     };
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Do you care about `complete` messages, and 2. what _do_ you want to do on error? ignore it and fail silently? restart the connection? some custom stuff?
It's hard to suggest a solution if we don't know that
Operators like `repeat`, `retry`, or `catchError` might be what you want, or for more manual stuff, `materialize`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do on error or on complete (does the websocket actually complete?)

I'm guessing you just want to log errors and complete normally:

```
public onMessage(): Observable<any>
{
  return this.ws$.pipe(catchError((err) => {
    console.log('error: ' + err); // Or remove this line
    return EMPTY; // resulting in "complete" instead of error
  }));
}
```

### Explanation

When you subscribe to an Observable, you can (optionally) define handlers to these notifications. Defining an error handler is like wrapping in `try-catch`, so in your example you could just do this in your component:

```
this.wsService.onMessage().subscribe(
  {
    next: (msg:any) => 
    {
      console.log('message received: ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
      this.doStuffInTheComponent(msg); //Method in Component
    },
    error: (_error: any) =>
    {
      // Ignore the error with an empty handler function
    }
  }
);
```

But it might make more sense to setup this logic in WebsocketService, for example to avoid repetition.

So my suggestion is adding a helper method in you WebsocketService that [pipes](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators#piping) through [`catchError`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError).
`catchError` works by defining a *new* Observable to replace the original one - only for the subscription, and only when there's an error.
So by doing `someObservable.pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY))`, I'm saying "if there's an error, just stop". ([`EMPTY`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY) is a utility Observable that just completes immediately).

### An alternative I discourage

You can achieve a similar result in a more imperative way by using a [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject).

I see devs at my company that aren't used to RxJS write code like this.
**I discourage it**, because it's twisting RxJS to look like code you might be more used to, instead of understanding how to work with it and leverage its strengths.
It usually leads to code that is more confusing and error prone.

I'll still include an example:

```
// In WebSocketService
public websocketIgoringErrors = new Subject<any>();
// If you do this, I recommend making websocketIgoringErrors private and doing this:
// public webSocketValues: Observable<any> = this.websocketIgoringErrors;
// So that other parts of the app can read new values, but only WebSocketService can put new values in it.

public connect(): void {
  this.ws$.subscribe(
    {
      next: msg => 
      {
        this.websocketIgoringErrors.next(msg);
      },
      error: err =>
      { 
        // Do nothing. Ignore error.
        // but you might want to do:
        // this.websocketIgoringErrors.complete();
      },
      complete:() =>
      { 
        // Like error, Do nothing.
        // but you might want to do:
        // this.websocketIgoringErrors.complete();
      },
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I’m not looking to do anything with the error. I want to make the Next method handler independently observable so the components can subscribe to it.

Comment: This will achieve that (just remove the console log). You can't exactly "make the Next method handler independently observable", because that's not how RxJS works. I'll add an explanation to my response